# Sqoop import sql server table process shows no progress

Tags: apache-http-server, sql-server, import, hadoop, sqoop

This is my first-try using Apache Sqoop to import a SQL Server table (6 columns, 4 records) to Hive. Below is the code.

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.10.101:1433;database=Testdb" --username abc--password abc --table "DimEmployee" --create-hive-table --hive-import --hive-table DboDimEmployee
```

The execution ran OK but stopped at this output

```
19/01/25 13:19:36 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1548438714494_0003
```

I checked the Hadoop UI web page. This particular application has no resource allocated to it and the progress is 0%. I am not sure what I did wrong.

Below is additional information.

1. The sql db connection parameters are correct and I have tested the connection from Hadoop side.
2. The Hive works fine. I was able to create a database or table in the hive.
3. The entire Hadoop system is in VirtualBox on my laptop. The master node has 4G memory and the data node has 1G memory.
4. Below is the only memory-related configurations I did on Hadoop. I am not sure the issue is related to memory and I posted it just in case.

   ```
   vi mapred-site.xml
     <property>
       <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
             <value>yarn</value>
     </property>
     <property>
           <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name>
           <value>256</value>
     </property>
     <property>
             <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
             <value>128</value>
     </property>
     <property>
             <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
             <value>128</value>
     </property>
   ```
5. I never saw the progress of map reduce, like % of map and % of reduce.
6. My installation did not have HBASE, HCatalog, Accumulo, or zookeeper. I do not think I need them but I might be wrong.
7. Below is all execution messages I got from Sqoop.

`Warning: /home/admin1/sqoop/../hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
    Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
    Warning: /home/admin1/sqoop/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
    Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
    Warning: /home/admin1/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
    Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
    Warning: /home/admin1/sqoop/../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
    Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
    19/01/28 09:56:12 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7
    19/01/28 09:56:12 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
    19/01/28 09:56:12 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override
    19/01/28 09:56:12 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.
    19/01/28 09:56:12 WARN sqoop.ConnFactory: Parameter --driver is set to an explicit driver however appropriate connection manager is not being set (via --connection-manage                           r). Sqoop is going to fall back to org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager. Please specify explicitly which connection manager should be used next time.
    19/01/28 09:56:12 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
    19/01/28 09:56:12 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
    19/01/28 09:56:12 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM DimEmployee AS t WHERE 1=0
    19/01/28 09:56:12 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM DimEmployee AS t WHERE 1=0
    19/01/28 09:56:12 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /home/admin1/hadoop
    Note: /tmp/sqoop-admin1/compile/e8e0b042e5ecc16c39484556762dae8a/DimEmployee.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    19/01/28 09:56:17 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-admin1/compile/e8e0b042e5ecc16c39484556762dae8a/DimEmployee.jar
    19/01/28 09:56:18 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of DimEmployee
    19/01/28 09:56:18 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
    19/01/28 09:56:18 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM DimEmployee AS t WHERE 1=0
    19/01/28 09:56:19 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
    19/01/28 09:56:19 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
    19/01/28 09:56:29 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation
    19/01/28 09:56:29 INFO db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: BoundingValsQuery: SELECT MIN(EmployeeKey), MAX(EmployeeKey) FROM DimEmployee
    19/01/28 09:56:29 INFO db.IntegerSplitter: Split size: 73; Num splits: 4 from: 1 to: 296
    19/01/28 09:56:29 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:4
    19/01/28 09:56:29 INFO Configuration.deprecation: yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled
    19/01/28 09:56:30 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1548697949348_0001
    19/01/28 09:56:31 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1548697949348_0001
    19/01/28 09:56:31 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://name1:8088/proxy/application_1548697949348_0001/
    19/01/28 09:56:31 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1548697949348_0001`

Comment: Don't you need to specify driver parameter too..... [`sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.10.101:1433;database=Testdb" --driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver  --username abc--password abc --table "DimEmployee" --create-hive-table --hive-import --hive-table DboDimEmployee`](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/89336/how-to-import-table-from-sql-server-into-hive-usin.html)

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  This will interfere with commenting, editing your own posts, and accepting an answer.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, these are https://superuser.com/users/990148/seaport and https://superuser.com/users/990149/seaport.  You’ll then be able to [edit] your question.

Comment: @Scott, I merged the two accounts. Thank you.

Comment: @Pimp Juice IT. Thanks for the comment. I specified the driver and got the same result. The driver may not be needed because I used the following code for testing connection and it worked as expected.   sqoop  list-databases --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.10.101:1433;database=Testdb" --username abc--password abc

Comment: I finally figured out that, the issue is not about Sqoop. It is about Hadoop, which has an unhealthy nodes due to disk space issue. After I resolved that, the Hadoop did not work well still due to memory issue related to Map Reduce. That has to be a new question. Thanks again for all comments.